# sql getting count of items from query result

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm querying my database grabbing all the information that is within it but, what i'm trying to do is grab all entries that have 'x' in a row and group them, then grab all entries that have 'y' in a row and group them.

I'm ideally trying to map each numeric month value to a javascript button. when you click on the Month 1 button you get all of the Month 1 entries that were grouped to display in a javascript table, along with a count of how many entries there are. Then the table will loop though the entries and print them on the screen.

I'm grabbing the entries with this statement

```
$myresult = customfunction($getCred, "Select * From Test_Data");
```

The name of the column for the months is NumericMonths,(integer)
For example lets say i want to group all the "Months"
This is the javascript table i have setup

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month1">Month 1(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month2">Month 2(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month3">Month 3(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month4">Month 4(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month5">Month 5(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month6">Month 6(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#Month7">Month 7(this is where the count of items should go)</a></li>
```

Then i want to loop though the the content depending on which button was picked with a loop

```
while ($row = custom_fetch_array($res)){

#My code here to generate a table such as $row["Name"] etc etc

};
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0):

This will get you two columns, i.e rows_per_month contain number of items for a month, and NumericMonths contain the month number. You will have max of 12 rows in the result.

```
 Select count(*) as rows_per_month, NumericMonths  From Test_Data group by NumericMonths
```

Fetch rows for requested month:

```
 Select * from Test_Data where NumericMonths = requested_month
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a bit tricky to work out what your setup is but never the less lets have a go.
To be honest make life easier on your php for the counts.

So use some SQL for the counts

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Test_Data WHERE NumbericMonths = 1;
```

If there are lots then this will make it easier.

Step 2 - the data.

I would do something like this. (psudo code)

```
$array = [];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Test_data "

foreach($row in $results) {
    $array[$row[month]] = $array[$row[month]] . '<tr><td>'.$row['something'].'</td></tr>';
}

 foreach($a in $array) {
       echo $a
}
```

That's really simple and I'm not sure I've done the foreach correctly - been a while since I've done php but the idea is there.